# How to change the footer content in WordPress Sparkling theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to change the footer content (copyright). I tried to change the `extras.php` file, but it does not work for me. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: inspect the element it will show came from  widget or hard code(footer.php). regard to that you can customize.

Answer (score 0):

**Appearance >> Customize >> Sparkling Options >> Footer**. This form supports HTML for URLs and other formatting. You can also change Footer background, text, link color via Theme Options.

Comment: i used this method but i dont get the answer.Can you please suggest  any other way

Answer (score 0):

Editing `extras.php` is the most convenient way. Comment out or remove part of code which prints out default copyright text. Which is:

> Theme by Colorlib Powered by WordPress

```
function sparkling_footer_info() {
        global $sparkling_footer_info;
/**
        printf( esc_html__( 'Theme by %1$s Powered by %2$s', 'sparkling' ) , '<a href="http://colorlib.com/" target="_blank">Colorlib</a>', '<a href="http://wor$
*/
}
```

After that it will be possible to add blank text or html to copyright field, from
Appearance >> Customize >> Sparkling Options >> Footer